# What skin to choose to create a Nexus 7, 10 emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I know that I can select a Device, Nexus 10 or Nexus 7. But what skin do I choose? 
WVGA800, HVGA, WXGA all show different screens. What to choose to get the real nexus 10 tab.

[image]

Comment: choose this skin WVGA800

Answer (score 1):

According to http://developer.android.com/tools/revisions/platforms.html (Android 4.2 device definitions) you should use WXGA